# Lining up buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have 3 paragraphs side by side, each with a button underneath. When the screen size changes so does the length of the paragraphs which moves the buttons out of line with each other.

Is there a way to make it if one button moves down the other ones will move with it so they all stay inline?

Comment: There is a good guide to equal height columns here, which I believe is the nature of your problem. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this could be:
Make you paragraph container *same height* and put your button *at the end of the container* of the paragraph and make its **position absolute** and the parent container must be **relative**. In this case if if paragraph height changes the button's position will not change *as it's out the content flow for absolute position*.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card p{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur maximus lobortis massa, at maximus erat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sem sapien, dictum congue elit quis, ultrices aliquam nunc. Phasellus bibendum augue augue, eget pharetra dolor faucibus eget. Vestibulum facilisis eros mollis, dictum mauris in, pharetra lacus. Aliquam sollicitudin sagittis magna, Suspendisse ullamcorper non leo tincidunt congue. Phasellus convallis mollis eros, sit amet sagittis orci auctor eu. Praesent erat orci, tempor at commodo ut, vulputate quis est. Nulla nec auctor nulla, a tincidunt massa.
    </p>
    <button class="btn">lulu</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>
      Vivamus volutpat lorem molestie congue tempor. Phasellus in ligula urna. Aliquam mi lectus, gravida eget tincidunt in, mattis vitae nibh. Suspendisse ullamcorper non leo tincidunt congue. Phasellus convallis mollis eros, sit amet sagittis orci auctor eu. Praesent erat orci, tempor at commodo ut, vulputate quis est. Nulla nec auctor nulla, a tincidunt massa.

      Integer nec dui ipsum. Vivamus malesuada id diam ac iaculis. Aliquam aliquam sagittis tortor non fringilla. Nullam maximus cursus leo quis dignissim. Nullam vehicula elit sit amet libero congue, id condimentum nibh dignissim. Nulla facilisi. Sed pretium tincidunt scelerisque. Nam accumsan sed diam vitae sagittis. Nam facilisis ex nisi, venenatis interdum ante tristique sit amet. Pellentesque consequat non magna a hendrerit. Integer laoreet sapien enim, nec pharetra est aliquam nec. Etiam ut euismod augue, ut feugiat turpis. Aenean pulvinar nec ligula vitae bibendum. Nam hendrerit leo ac vulputate maximus. Sed eu tincidunt est.</p>
    <button class="btn">lulu</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur maximus lobortis massa, at maximus erat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sem sapien,

      Vivamus volutpat lorem molestie congue tempor. Phasellus in ligula urna. Aliquam mi lectus, gravida eget tincidunt in, mattis vitae nibh. Suspendisse ullamcorper non leo tincidunt congue. Phasellus convallis mollis eros, sit amet sagittis orci auctor eu. Praesent erat orci, tempor at commodo ut, vulputate quis est. Nulla nec auctor nulla, a tincidunt massa.

      Integer nec dui ipsum. Vivamus malesuada id diam ac iaculis. Aliquam aliquam sagittis tortor non fringilla. Nullam maximus cursus leo quis dignissim. Nullam vehicula elit sit amet libero congue, id condimentum nibh dignissim. Nulla facilisi. </p>
    <button class="btn">lulu</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You first need to wrap the paragraph with its according button into a wrapper element.

Then you need to make sure that this wrapper elements always have the same height.

Last you need to position the buttons. Here you can make use of flexbox. Take a look at the property justify-content.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to achieve this using [Flex](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox):

1. Add a parent `<article>` to the `paragraph` and `button` elements.
2. Give them a `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

This will be enough to always make the buttons align with each other at the bottom.

```css
section{
    display:flex;
    padding:20px;
}

article{
    flex-basis:33%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width:500px){
    section{
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
    article{
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
    <article><h1>1</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Est mollitia beatae repudiandae assumenda rerum reprehenderit, soluta quam laudantium vero doloribus reiciendis quidem accusantium delectus amet facere consequatur eum, suscipit consectetur iure eligendi, impedit non. Corporis exercitationem qui consectetur ipsa quam.</p><button>read more</button></article>
    <article><h1>1</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Est mollitia beatae repudiandae assumenda rerum reprehenderit, soluta quam laudantium vero doloribus reiciendis quidem accusantium delectus amet facere consequatur eum, suscipit consectetur iure eligendi, impedit non. Corporis exercitationem qui consectetur ipsa quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, adipisci?</p><button>read more</button></article>
    <article><h1>1</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quibusdam laudantium illo quidem expedita beatae ratione quaerat culpa dolorem reprehenderit numquam provident aliquid molestiae sint voluptate, dolore repudiandae nemo impedit? consectetur, adipisicing elit. Est mollitia beatae repudiandae assumenda rerum reprehenderit, soluta quam laudantium vero doloribus reiciendis quidem accusantium delectus amet facere consequatur eum, suscipit consectetur iure eligendi, impedit non. Corporis exercitationem qui consectetur ipsa quam.</p><button>read more</button></article>
</section>
```